Persisting ComSpec issue flagged by VSC despite everything is set correctly
I have a persisting ComSpec issue flagged by VSC despite everything is set correctly.
"We detected an issue with one of your environment variables that breaks features such as IntelliSense, linting and debugging. Try setting the "ComSpec" variable to a valid Command Prompt path in your system to fix it.
Sourcce: Python"
Note: I am using Windows 11 and Visual Studio Code version:
Version: 1.88.1 (system setup)
Commit: e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
Date: 2024-04-10T17:41:02.734Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
I checked the Python Interpreter repeatedly and everything is properly set and pointing to C:\Program Files where Python.exe is
BUT! Every time I exited VSC and open a python file? The error message indicating ComSpec issue at environment variables appears.
Anyone knows what's going on? how to rectify this?
**What have I tried?
I checked ComSpec environment multiple times and everything is properly set
I checked the path for both User variables and System variables and it is also set properly
I also checked in VSC terminal setting and everything is also properly set
I checked the terminal error message - Nothing. No error there.
What am I expecting?
I am expecting this error won't be appearing anymore or it would be helpful IF VSC helps pinpoint and elaborate on the cause and suggest specific solutions instead of getting us scouring everywhere to troubleshoot. I know its a tall order but it's just a wishful thinking - an AI debugger

What exactly is your COMSPEC set to?

C:%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
But I think I solved the issue already for now. The problem isn't with the ComSpec as it is set correctly.
I simply uninstall and re-install Python Extension - debugger and pylance.
It worked... for now (fingers crossed). Thanks for responding.
I will update this there, IF is still problem (hopefully not)
